# How can I rotate the camera around my character with my weapon out?

Tags: fallout-4

It's easy to rotate the camera around my character while not in combat mode in 3rd person, but how can I do it in combat mode? I have tried pressing F and using the Middle Mouse Button, but nothing happens.

Comment: well, I can be wrong but, the main focus being in combat mode is to keep the camera focused where you're pointing your weapon, so you can shoot or hit whatever you're pointing to, why would want to look where you're not fighting when in combat mode?

Comment: @ViniciusTerrabuio - I have good gear and weapon, so I want to film video spining around my character in this gear. That's why I want rotate camera in combat mode. For simple screenshot I could use simple 'tfc' console command, but this won't give me rotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hold F (for me it's actually V (same key I use to switch between 1st and 3rd person views), not sure if I remapped something or not) or middle mouse while you move the mouse around.

If you're using a gamepad then you should hold the button that puts the camera into 3rd person mode, and then rotate the camera around your character. For example X-Box 360 gamepad this would be the Back button.

Comment: That's strange, it didn't work first time for me. Maybe it's because I've tried F, when the right button was V for me.

Comment: Standard button is V, Downside is, you can't do it in settlements... *meh*